# Como eu faço tratamento de Variáveis no PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o Seguinte Código no PHP:

**Array:**

```
$eqCodigos  = $_POST["eqCodigo"];
```

**Tentativa de Tratamento para gravar no MySQl**

```
$eqCodigo1 = explode("\n", $eqCodigos);
$eqCodigo2 = array_filter($eqCodigo1);
$eqCodigo  = trim($eqCodigo2);
```

**Query mysql_query**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eq_Codigos (idEquipamento, cdCodigo, cdOpAlteracao, cdDtAlteracao) VALUES ('$idEquipamento', '$eqCodigo[0]', '$eqOpAlteracao', NOW()), ('$idEquipamento', '$eqCodigo[1]', '$eqOpAlteracao', NOW())")
```

**Export da tabela depois do INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO `eq_Codigos` (`idCodigo`, `idEquipamento`, `cdCodigo`, `cdOpAlteracao`, `cdDtAlteracao`) VALUES (27, 164, '123\r', 'Jonatas Messias', '2016-09-23 10:06:16'), (28, 164, '987', 'Jonatas Messias', '2016-09-23 10:06:16');
```

Só que na hora que salva no banco o primeiro código do Array fica com "\r" no final, dificultando na hora que vou fazer o Select.

Comment: Você pode usar uma expressão regular para retirar aonde tiver o /r `$ret = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $eqCodigos);`

Comment: Mas eu posso deixar o Código do jeito que esta ou eu posso usar essa expressão no lugar do trim?

Comment: @FlavioMisawa o que essa RegEx era para fazer? `^` iniciando no final?

Comment: `\r` ou `/r`? qual deles

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é \r, editei a pergunta e coloquei o export da tabela após o insert para você vê como que fica no MySql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro eu gostaria de apontar alguns erros no seu código, para analisarmos a situação:

```
$eqCodigo1 = explode("\n", $eqCodigos); // Isso vira um `array`
$eqCodigo2 = array_filter($eqCodigo1); // Certo, o `array` será filtrado
$eqCodigo  = trim($eqCodigo2); // Usar trim num `array` vai gerar erro, pois ele espera uma `string`.
```

A primeira coisa a ser feita no caso é mudar esse código para:

```
$eqCodigo1 = explode("\n", $eqCodigos);
$eqCodigo2 = array_filter($eqCodigo1);
$eqCodigo  = array_map('trim', $eqCodigo2);
```

Uma das situações a serem feitas aqui é verificar que alguns sistemas operacionais a quebra de linha é `\r\n`, e não somente `\n`.

Ao fazer um teste com a seguinte `string`:

```
  explode("\n", "\r\n a" )
```

O Resultado foi:

```
[
  "\r",
  " a",
]
```

Ou seja, observe que `\r` "ficou para trás". A minha solução para isso, seria primeiramente tratando os dados, para que eles fiquem padronizados para `\n` sempre.

Ou seja:

```
  explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $eqCodigos));
```

Se quiser ressumir o processo de declaração de variáveis, você ainda pode fazer assim:

```
$eqCodigo = array_map('trim', array_filter(explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $eqCodigos))));
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado a sua Solução e explicação me ajudaram muito. Consegui resolver o problema! Usando  o resumo que você passou!